# Fragment Pager Adapter get an error

Tags: java, android, xml

this is my Fragment Page Adapter.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private String[] pageTitle = {
            "Page1", "Page2", "Page3"
    };

    public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0: return new PageFragment();
        case 1: return new PageFragment2();
        case 2: return new PageFragment3();
        }
        Fragment fragment = new PageFragment();
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putString("pageIndex", Integer.toString(position + 1));
        fragment.setArguments(arguments);
        return fragment;

   }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return pageTitle.length;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return pageTitle[position];
    }

}
```

Why i get an error in this line: case 0: return new PageFragment(); and Fragment fragment = new PageFragment(); the error is "Type mismatch: cannot convert from PageFragment to Fragment" How to fix? Is possible make it (Viewpager) compatible with Android 2.2 or 2.3?

Comment: Does `PageFragment extends Fragment`?  Can you post the source of `PageFragment`?

Comment: yes its possible to useViewPager with Android 2.2, as its from the supportv4 Library

Comment: Sorry if I was not very precise. I eventually solved alone. Thank you all and sorry again.

Answer (score 0):

`PageFragment` should extend `Fragement` or another Fragment class (e.g. `ListFragment`). You haven't posted a code for `PageFragment` so it's hard to say.

Also, I understand you have 3 pages only so the code in `getItem` is not effective as it will always return in one of the cases of `switch` and the code after `switch` will never be reached.